# Aurelia TS pulling map from a map

Tags: aurelia

I have a `Map<string, Map<string, boolean>>` defined in my appConfig.json and when I try and get values from the map using .get() I get an error that it is not a function.

This is in my appConfig.json

```
"rolePermissions" : [
    {"name" : "Admin", "value" : [
      {"name" : "customerList", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "customerDetails", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "addCustomerUser", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "editCustomer", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "updateBackend", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "createCustomer", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "jobsList", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "jobsView", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "jobsEdit", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "jobsDownload", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "usersList", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "usersEdit", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "usersDelete", "value" : "true"},
      {"name" : "usersCreate", "value" : "true"}
    ]}
```

and I have set the property in my appConfig.ts as:
public rolePermissions: Map>;

This is how I'm accessing rolePermissions:

```
let rolePerms = this.appConfig.rolePermissions;

let rolePerm = rolePerms.get("Admin");
```

When I try and pull the "Admin" value from the map I get an error:

```
ERROR [app-router] TypeError: rolePerms.get is not a function
    at Utils.userRoleAuthorized (utils.ts:29)
    at NewCustomer.canActivate (newCustomer.ts:42)
    at iterate (index.ts:7)
    at processActivatable (index.ts:7)
    at CanActivateNextStep.run (index.ts:7)
    at next (index.ts:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (shell.ts:58)
    at step (vendor-bundle.js:4344)
    at Object.next (vendor-bundle.js:4325)
    at vendor-bundle.js:4318
    at Promise._execute (vendor-bundle.js:824)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (vendor-bundle.js:2601)
    at new Promise (vendor-bundle.js:2197)
    at __awaiter (vendor-bundle.js:4314)
    at Object.run (shell.ts:45)
    at next (index.ts:7)
```

Comment: consider using bitmask flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I didn't catch that you file is a `json`, the original post still applies though.

If you cannot convert your `rolePermissions` to a `Map`, you'll need to process it like a regular array:

```
rolePerms.find(x => x.name === "Admin").value
```

**ORIGINAL:**

The way you initialize `rolePermissions` is your problem.
You're actually not creating a `Map`, but an Array.
Therefore the function `get` is not available, since `get` is not a function defined on the array prototype.

Here's how you'd need to do it:

```
const rolePermissions = new Map<string, Map<string, boolean>>(
    [
        [
            "Admin", new Map<string, boolean>([
                ["customerList", true],
                ["customerDetails", true],
                ["addCustomerUser", true],
                ["editCustomer", true],
                ["updateBackend", true],
                ["createCustomer", true],
                ["jobsList", true],
                ["jobsView", true],
                ["jobsEdit", true],
                ["jobsDownload", true],
                ["usersList", true],
                ["usersEdit", true],
                ["usersDelete", true],
                ["usersCreate", true]
            ])
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `appConfig.json` is, but it is definitely a JSON file, so they won't be able to write this code in that file. They'd need to put the call to the `Map` constructor in their application code, and pass the value from the JSON file to it.

Comment: Correct, thanks for pointing this out! I missed the `json` part.